# How to get "Fast Web View" property value from pdf using python or any other source?

Tags: python, pypdf, pdfminer, pymupdf, tika-python

Is there a way to extract Fast Web View property value programmatically? Python would be preferred.

Thanks
Manohar

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Use your preferred native OS bash (grep) or cmd console (find)

I had to download a known Adobe sample file https://github.com/adobe/pdf-embed-api-samples/tree/master/More%20Samples/Linearization because none of my hundreds of test PDF downloads was designed to be served via web.

Here is the Windows version.

```
for /r %f in (*.pdf) do @type "%f" | find "/Linearized">nul && echo Found web view in "%f"
```

Result

`Found web view in "C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Downloads\Bodea Brochure - linear copy.pdf"`

Using a larger set of PDFs I got a return listing, including duplicates, of 335 from 2432 PDFs thus under 15% in that case.